# How to Make SO questions more Google-Friendly

Tags: discussion, questions

Glancing at the SO homepage I found that a lot of questions are asked in such a way that it's not easy for Google to find them. Any idea how to fix this?

P/S: I know that this is entirely up to the users to ask good question. But maybe we can do something to "improve their odds" of asking good questions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The biggest point about finding questions with Google is the same for finding content of any sort through Google: **it's all about the title**.

So pick a good title that succinctly gives people an idea of what the question is about. Sometimes it can be hard thinking of a good title. I've sometimes spent some serious time thinking of a good title for things (blog posts and so on).

Compare and contrast:

- "I'm confused";
- "This doesn't work"; and
- "What do I do?"

vs

- "I don't understand why Java isn't cleaning up my thread pool";
- "Why is this code giving me a NullPointerException?"; and
- "My Ruby page takes 10 seconds to load. How do I find out why?"

Also think about likely search terms if you were looking for this question. You will get a higher ranking for something which is an exact phrase match than with something than isn't (generally speaking).

Comment: Personally, I don't even think "Why is this code giving me a NullPointerException?" is particularly good; you still have to read the question to know if you have any idea about the issue, and it certainly doesn't help searchability -- anybody trying to fix a problem by Googling "NullPointerException" is going to have serious problems. I would usually try to frame that question title by (e.g) the call the code is making, rather than a super-generic symptom ('throwing NullPointerException').

Answer (score 3):

Just clean up the grammar, wording, and clarity. It you build it, Google will come :)