# How to contribute to Stack Overflow besides asking and answering?

Tags: discussion, contribution

Besides contributing [great questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13438/how-to-make-so-questions-more-google-friendly) and answers, are there any other ways that I can contribute to Stack Overflow and its family of websites?

I would be happy to

1. give a [PayPal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PayPal) donation
2. contribute code

SFOU has been helping me tremendously, so it's only fair if I can give back something.

Comment: Searching for the same thing, you asked for the same thing. :)

Comment: What does SFOU mean?

Comment: If I want to help a beta site, can I contribute financially?

Comment: They wouldn't want my code!  How about a patreon setup, or a bitcoin donations address ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Clean up other people's contributions. Additionally, flag inappropriate postings, and vote to close/migrate questions when necessary.

Sporting your flair elsewhere brings more attention to SO as well.

Answer (score 20):

Support their advertisers. Or, at least turn off AdBlock for these sites.

Answer (score 20):

**Vote**. SO and the rest of the family are crowdsourcing quality control. So vote both up and down, both questions and answers. Propose **edits**, and when you have the rep just flat out perform edits to make things better. **Retag**, too. **Flag** - questions, answers, and comments - so that everyone knows that crap has no lifespan on the site. **Promote** the site with flair on your blog, by tweeting or facebooking links, by putting your SO profile name on your resume, by telling newbies in your industry what a great resource it is. Hang out on meta and **learn the culture** of your site, then help others to learn it. Come to the site **every day** and contribute in one of these ways every day.

Everything else, they can buy. But what each of us does every day for free is what gives the site its value. Keep doing it.

Comment: +1 for your last sentence...well, second to last.

Answer (score 13):

**Edit, edit, edit!**

Prior to SO, there have existed many, many Q&A sites, forums, newsgroups, etc. dedicated to answering or discussing programming problems. The **one big thing** SO brings to the table is the ability to take a poorly-written question or badly-formatted answer and make it better: easier to read, easier to find, easier to understand. You may not be the *fastest gun in the west*, but if you can scrape together a reputation score of 2K then you can edit almost every post on the site - and do so at your leisure. And even if you don't have the 2K, you can still *suggest* edits.

If SO hasn't become a steaming pile 5 years from now, it'll be because enough people took a little bit of their time to edit it into something better.

---

Now that *anyone* can suggest edits, editing should be the primary choice for anyone wishing to contribute in ways other than asking or answering... But here are some other suggestions:

- Find existing duplicates of new questions and link to them from comments - dup-finding is a win-win situation most of the time, as the OP gets answers faster and the site gets less noise. Flag them for moderator review (use the close as duplicate option) after you've posted a link.
- Review answers in your area of expertise and point out problems, or post suggestions for improvement as comments.
- Flag abusive / spam posts or unhelpful comments.

Answer (score 12):

I don't think they are in search of either of what you are asking.

No word yet on whether they would accept offerings of sheep and goats.

It is also unknown how well they look upon human sacrifice.

Comment: *It is also unknown how well they look upon human sacrifice.*

I love this phase.

Comment: You get way too much rep for these types of answers ;)

Comment: Good news is he hits the rep cap fast so a lot of what he would otherwise gain goes to waste.

Comment: @Jonathan: I've been at rep cap for quite some time. Most of my goofy answers just look pretty but never really do much for me.

Comment: @EBGreen: basically. I'll post a few things that get me a lot of rep and then the rest of my crap is just there.

Comment: Meanwhile, others are working to provide real answers ;) The cap is more difficult to achieve that way. No harm done - this *is* meta.

Comment: @TheTXI: what are you talking about? SO *loves* human sacrifice! SO is **built** on human sacrifice! SO lives on the daily offering of small portions of many lives...

Comment: I thought SO liked waffles.

Comment: *I* like waffles.

Comment: With     butter?

Comment: Yes! *Real* butter! And maple syrup!

Comment: Didn't [user 52443](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/52443/) give up his mortal body?

Comment: Ponies are always welcome.

Answer (score 3):

One important thing is to try to get as many people as you can to SE sites, tell them about how great the sites are.

If the community grows, then the traffic increases
If the traffic increases, then more ads are displayed
If more ads are displayed, then the odds of someone finding interesting products increase
If ...

Well, you get the idea.

Answer (score 3):

Having a place to donate would still be quite nice.

I don't work in code, my knowledge is mediocre at best, and I don't have much time, but this website helps me a ton in my hobby of learning to code and I would be happy to help a little.

A quick search showed they raised $85M in 2020. This would indicate they are not profitable yet. I don't know code, but I know finance and I would expect there is a risk that investors (their VC are very reputable though) may put some degree of pressure to monetize SO which may be achieved in a way that may or may not be aligned with the community's desires.

There are 120 million unique visitors each month, and a little from many of us could go a long way.

It would be nice to have SO's opinion as I am sure they have thought of it.

Comment: But their VC is [out of it](https://techcrunch.com/2021/06/02/stack-overflow-acquired-by-prosus-for-a-reported-1-8-billion/) now(?).

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum  you are right, I looked only at the press release from July 28,  2020. did not notice the acquisition by Prosus.

Answer (score 1):

Post links to interesting questions/answers to Twitter and Facebook.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. When I see a SO question on reddit or HN (I have no twitter or facebook accounts), it's usually a bad open ended discussion question which should have started and stayed on reddit but isn't really suited for SO. So I'd say that to promote good questionnig, post interesting questions when they're fit for SO.