# How can I help stackoverflow outside of the site?

Tags: discussion, support, contribution

I'm probably just being an idiot, but are there any ways that we can help out stackoverflow outside of visiting the site itself? [There's a list of things we can do besides just posting on the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17310/how-to-contribute-to-stackoverflow-besides-asking-and-answering), but I just wanted to ask if there are any additional things we could do to <s>beat the crap out of expert sexchange</s> help the site we love so much! :D (reviewing it on other websites, linking to it from blogs, spreading the word, etc.)

Comment: Yes, there are things you can do outside the website, such as: reviewing it on other websites, linking to it from blogs, spreading the word, etc.

Comment: @Koper any specific other websites you have in mind? :D

Answer (score 5):

Well at [DDD8](http://www.developerdeveloperdeveloper.com/ddd8/) last weekend (at Microsoft's Reading UK HQ) there just *might* have been some random developer going around with a brown envelope filled with [trilogy stickers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/how-to-get-stack-overflow-stickers/). I didn't recognise <s>me</s> him though.

Comment: Good thing then that developers are practical people that don't fall for something like stickers, right?

Answer (score 1):

An obvious answer, talk it up with people you meet. I'm not much of a programmer, so I talk up serverfault and superuser, especially with people who aren't engineers.

Comment: I talk up S.O. to programming friends, Server Vault to IT collegues, and random other stacks(?) to random other friends....it's (stackexchange) really a site that anyone could learn from.