# Can I give a donation to Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, donation, contribution

I have learned so much from SE sites and I am really thankful for it.
I sometimes feel that I am under debt from SO, so in order to satisfy me and my principles, I think I should give some donation.

I want to contribute but I don't have much technical expertise to use in helping others, so maybe if I can give a donation, this would help me to feel better.

I have been a member of various other forums and I have always given some amount (not much, though) to them as thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicates [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16378/add-a-paypal-link-to-accept-donations) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17310/how-to-contribute-to-stackoverflow-besides-asking-and-answering)

Comment: Log out clear your cookies and cache then visit the sites not logged in and buy stuff from the ads.

Comment: The answers [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17310/how-to-contribute-to-stackoverflow-besides-asking-and-answering) are really fantastic. There are tons of ways to help improve the site beyond monetary donations and contributing answers. Cleaning up low-quality content provided by others is *extremely* important, especially on Stack Overflow. Also see here: [How can I help stackoverflow outside of the site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38617/how-can-i-help-stackoverflow-outside-of-the-site).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It has been said before: the best donation is to contribute to the site. Ask great questions and give superb answers.

Answer (score 9):

Deactivate any AdBlockers <strike>and/or buy something [from the store](http://shop.stackexchange.com/)</strike>.

Unfortunately, the shop is no more, so there's only making good contributions and look at those pretty ads.

Comment: No shop makes the 404 page a sad panda.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should make distinction between **the platform** and **the community**. Platform is indeed created by Stack Exchange Inc., but the community is just people from all over the world, most of who no relation to Stack Exchange Inc. at all.

- if you want to help Stack Exchange Inc. — do as Bobby suggests in his answer;
- if you want to help the community — do as Gamecat suggests, besides providing answers there are many more ways of contributing. You can flag answers and questions. You can suggest edits to improve them. And most importantly you can up-vote good ones, down-vote bad ones.

Answer (score 1):

- Submit edits for poor quality questions/answers
- Flag/vote to migrate off-topic questions
- Upvote good questions!
- Upvote good answers!