# Why not introduce a donate button in Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, donation

Since Stack Exchange is doing pretty well what it was meant to do, isn't a donate button worth it?

This would help support site expenses in a better manner. There would be people willing to donate, since the series of sites has done so much for the world. It's not easy to manage something like this so efficiently. It's perfect and deserves some crowd funding/donations.

Comment: why so many downvotes without a single reason?....A donation is not compulsory!!.

Comment: Is this a bad idea?

Comment: [Voting is different on meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). People are just disagreeing with you. But if they want then [My favourite charity](http://www.horsesensewirral.com/donate-3)

Comment: @Iain Oh that means..downvotes denote that they are not in support of this idea??

Comment: Begging for donations mean the company is having hard time to maintain its resources and stay alive. Wikipedia keeps begging with huge banners and warnings, Firefox started doing it now too in some recent browser update. Stack Exchange doesn't need to beg for donations simply because they don't need them, and it will cause more harm than good.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard I agree with you but I disagree about that wikipedia part.Wikipedia is an amazing online encyclopedia.They have no source of income.They don't even put up ads.And after all now they are trying to negotiate with the network carriers around the world to make surfing on wikipedia be free of cost.That's something amazing.A lot of people will have an access to a lot of knowlede if they are not rich enough to subscribe for an internet plan.They need donations for that!

Comment: @Shadow Wizard According to me,donations cannot be compared to begging because someone asks for a donation to do something good for others(in most cases).For example,if stack exchange takes it,it will obviously be using the money to improve the services.

Comment: I never said Wikipedia is not amazing. Just stated the facts, and that potential investors will think twice before investing in a company that need donations to keep going, (Which is implied by having a "Donate" button.)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard...no.offence.I was just expressing my thoughts.

Comment: Fair enough, and in case you missed it, you'll probably find this interesting: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17310/how-to-contribute-to-stack-overflow-besides-asking-and-answering.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard ...That link helped..I am turning of adblock just now for this site.!!..I would like to contribute in a manner SO considers as ideal..And this shall be the beginning!

Comment: Find out if someone needs cashflow before volunteering to donate money to them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> It's perfect and deserves some crowd funding/donations.

That is very nice. It is always nice that users appreciate the work of all the volunteers within the network and employees of Stack Overflow Inc.

A donate button is an option indeed, but Stack Overflow Inc. has other ways to create revenues. Advertisements are one of them. Low-reputation users are shown advertisements which contribute to the revenue of the company. Also Stack Overflow Jobs (aka Careers) brings in some of money (judging on the number of people working on it, it is the greatest contributor to the revenue).

Stack Overflow Inc. doesn't do crowd-funding at the moment, they have other means of getting funding. See for example [this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/andreessen-horowitz-invests-in-stack-exchange/) and [this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/02/podcast-62-delete-this-whole-episode/) blog post.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for them already. Thanks @rene

Comment: Yeah,the answer does make sense.But I don't get it.Adding a donate button isn't forcing someone to donate.It's voluntary as the word says 'donate'.

Comment: Donations are usually for non-profit organisations. I guess SOI has another philosophy on how they want to create revenue. Also, some might feel they are earning it through the posts the community posts.

Comment: Well,opinions could vary.I respect your opinion though.No offence!

Comment: Are the programmers working with stack exchange volunteers?..Aren't they paid??

Comment: Yes, they are paid.

Comment: @Mathews actually, this very site (MSE) is by all means the QA (Quality Assurance :-)) for Stack Exchange. They do not hire QA team because they have many people doing exactly this, right here. So in some sense, by being active here, finding bugs, etc, you also can help them save money, which is similar to  donation.

Comment: It should be noted that paid advertisements do not appear on all sites. (See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243521).)

Comment: Hey, the mods!!